# How to solve "AttributeError: 'FirefoxProfile' object has no attribute 'capabilities'" EagleEye git

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/blc/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_finder.py",      line 38, in get_path
path = SeleniumManager().driver_location(options) if path is None else path
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 File "/home/blc/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/selenium_manager.py", line 84, in driver_location
browser = options.capabilities["browserName"]
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'FirefoxProfile' object has no attribute 'capabilities'

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/blc/Tools/EagleEye/eagle-eye.py", line 229, in <module>
main(skipFB=args.skipfb, FBUrls=[], jsonRep=jsonRepFile, dockerMode=aDocker, dockerName=aName)
File "/home/blc/Tools/EagleEye/eagle-eye.py", line 99, in main
f.grabData()
File "/home/blc/Tools/EagleEye/grabber/facebook.py", line 16, in grabData
driver = cfg.getWebDriver()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/blc/Tools/EagleEye/utils/config.py", line 45, in getWebDriver
return webdriver.Firefox(profile)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/blc/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 59, in __init__
self.service.path = DriverFinder.get_path(self.service, options)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/blc/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_finder.py", line 40, in get_path
msg = f"Unable to obtain driver for {options.capabilities['browserName']} using Selenium Manager."
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'FirefoxProfile' object has no attribute 'capabilities'
```

I'm trying a tools,eagleeye(github) and I have a problem when I try to run the script ? Someone has an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same for me,
Debian 12
Changed geckodriver to version 17 as I'm using Firefos ESR , reinstall selenium package, path to webdriver is good in config.json
... and still KO ....

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).